# Magento 2: How to setup Elasticsearch from CLI?

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, elasticsearch

We need to setup elasticsearch on Magento 2 when a new container starts.
We have post-install scripts that could handle that and not have someone go into the admin and manually do it.

Thanks.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Found a way to do it.
We added these commands to our post-install script:

```
magento config:set catalog/search/engine 'elasticsearch5'
magento config:set catalog/search/elasticsearch5_server_hostname 'elasticsearch-hostname.env'
```

You can also configure other things like ports:

```
magento config:set catalog/search/elasticsearch5_server_port '9200'
magento config:set catalog/search/elasticsearch5_index_prefix 'magento2'
magento config:set catalog/search/elasticsearch5_enable_auth '0'
magento config:set catalog/search/elasticsearch5_server_timeout '15'
```

These are the engine options:

```
mysql - MySQL
elasticsearch - Elasticsearch
elasticsearch5 - Elasticsearch5.0+
```

If you decide to use variables on the server_hostname, you must use double quotes:

```
magento config:set catalog/search/elasticsearch5_server_hostname "elasticsearch-$MY_VARIABLE.env"
```

Comment: thank you, do you know how to list all available config path like `catalog/search/engine` and `catalog/search/elasticsearch5_server_hostname`?

Comment: @JaredChu You can find in code: https://github.com/magento/magento2/tree/2.4-develop/app/code/Magento

Search for Elasticsearch, Elasticsearch6 and Elasticsearch7.

https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.4-develop/app/code/Magento/Elasticsearch7/etc/config.xml#L12

`<engine>elasticsearch7</engine>`

Comment: Keeping the magento config:set catalog/search/elasticsearch5_server_hostname 'locahost' worked fine for me.

Comment: @Jason that only works if elasticsearch is running locally. We were running on other pods.

Answer (score 2):

If you use elasticsearch 7 use these commands (change values according to your needs):

```
magento config:set catalog/search/engine 'elasticsearch7'
magento config:set catalog/search/elasticsearch7_server_hostname 'localhost'
magento config:set catalog/search/elasticsearch7_server_port '9200'
magento config:set catalog/search/elasticsearch7_index_prefix 'magento2'
magento config:set catalog/search/elasticsearch7_enable_auth '0'
magento config:set catalog/search/elasticsearch7_server_timeout '15'
```